# Sliding underline border to work with the active web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get this sliding border nav bar to work with an active page navbar highlight.  I want it's default position to be on the page that is currently active.
http://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon
`<script>$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("current");</script>`

I'm using this java script to get the current page.

My nav bar is set up like this.  This is the li class "two"s specific code for it to be highlighted.

```
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="one"><a href="WhoWeAre.html">Who we are</a></li><!--
   --><li class="two"><a class"current" href="WhatWeDo.html">What we do</a></li><!--
   --><li class="three"><a href="GetInvolved.html">Get Involved</a></li><!--
   --><li class="four"><a href="Schedule.html">Event Schedule</a></li><!--
   --><li class="five"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <hr />
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And I want to use a.current{} in my css but I can't get it to work with the sliding border.  I've tried putting it in with these, just using commas but it isn't working.

```
.two:hover ~ hr, a.current {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr, a.current  {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr, a.current  {
  margin-left: 60%;
}

.five:hover ~ hr, a.current  {
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.bar hr, a.current  {
  height: 4px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(248, 172, 48);
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: instead of adding class `current` for `a` add it for `li` and then `two.current`

Comment: http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/rxWgpB

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for. Thank you!  Is it possible to still have it slide to the left?

Comment: *Is it possible to still have it slide to the left?* means you want to change it on click ? each page is different?  `<a href="WhoWeAre.html">` ? or you want to animate the `border` once the page is loaded?

Comment: The edited code on codepen doesn't allow for animation to the left if you select a page that is on the right.

Comment: http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/rxWgpB check this

Comment: You can click on the items to the left but they don't hover.

Comment: @johnstamos wondering whether the answer helped..!

Comment: @johnstamos Tj answer works use it

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following. I've added a click event to keep the border below clicked item. You can just do `$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").parent().addClass("current");` if you don't want such behaviour.

Note that `/js` is the value of `location.pathname` in the snippet. Also note the specificity trick on the hover selectors so that the border can slide backwards.

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
}).has("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("current");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 300 100%'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.one.current ~ hr,
ul li.one:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.two.current ~ hr,
li.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.three.current ~ hr,
.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Who we are</a>
    </li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">What we do</a>
    </li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#/js">Get Involved</a>
    </li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use 5 menu items?  How would the specificity trick work then?

Comment: @johnstamos you can always increase the specificity by adding more selectors like `body ul li..`, `html body ul li..` or just add an id to first item `ul li#myid ...` etc... read the rules of specificity

Comment: Yes.  Alternating ul li and li seems to work as well. One issue with this design though.  Random clicks elsewhere on the screen resets the border to the initial furthest left menu option.  Suggestions?

Comment: @johnstamos I'm not sure what you're asking. the question was about positioning the sliding bar below the active page... The click was just and addition from my side... If you have new issues based on an answer, please ask different questions.

Comment: This current solution breaks when clicking on a message or input field on that page.  The underline defaults/falls back to the left.  Would we be able to account for this in our JS, say, only remove current and add new current if click is on when of our menu options?

Comment: @johnstamos There  was no input field or message in question, That's a different problem. This is a `Q&A` site, you ask a question and you get the answer for what you asked, we can't future proof all the other issues you might face in your project. If you are unable to fix those, you should ask different questions...

Comment: Well right, but usually people try to give solutions that don't break upon another extremely common feature being used.  I shouldn't have to point out that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't break when someone clicks on the page.  I feel the solution can be improved so I suggested an if statement to see if we could make it better.

Comment: @johnstamos like i said, If i didn't give this answer, you would be stuck where you was when you asked the question. So you should accept the answer that fixed the problem you asked. If you face new issues later, you should try to fix them, if you can't ask different question showing the html  structure, inputs messages etc. that's how the site works.

Comment: Right, I do think this could be an acceptable answer if we approved upon it's glaring weakness, perhaps with an if statement.

Comment: @johnstamos you posted some html and css and a problem statement, and i gave a working solution based on the given html and css. It does solve the question that was asked. There was no inputs, messages or anything in question. I can't give a lecture on event bubbling, sorry